# Custom Registration form

Tags: wordpress, customization, user-registration

I have created a template on my WordPress theme to use as a custom registration form. The form already submit, but the problem is that I cant assign a user role on submission.

How can I add a user role once the form is submitted?

Comment: Can you post your code after submission ?

Comment: You can create a hidden input field in your form there you can assign user role static either dynamic(using hook).

Answer (score 0):

Once new user is created by wp_create_user function, you can set any default or custom role for him/her.
It should look like this:

```
$user_name='Some_name';
$user_password='Some_password';
$user_email='some_email@example.com';

$user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $user_password, $user_email );
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->set_role( 'editor' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here is example of custom registration form [url](http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html) : http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html

Comment: Thanks. how can i add some extra fields like phone number, or business name, then show that value on the profile page in wordpress admin?

Comment: @MarvynSue 

Check this url for custom field add : https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form